# Wall mount Rotary Dimmer installed on lamp cord?

Tags: dimmer, lamp

Could I do something like the diagram below, or is this a technically bad idea?

[image]

I like the feel of this rotary dimmer and was wondering if it was safe to install it on the cord between the outlet and the lamp.

On top of that, I would then like to install a touch On/Off so that I can simply tap the lamp to turn off the light at the defined dimness. Then when I touch the lamp again to turn it on, the dimness would be at what it was when the lamp turned off.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: 2 BIG issues here.1) This is not to code, even if you ground the controller using the green ground wire from the AC outlet.2) The Touch On/Off circuit will be confused the the chopped AC pulses the dimmer puts out. It may not work right on a dim setting.

Comment: You're better off with an extension cord with a touch dimmer built-in.

Comment: @Sparky256 - Is anything which I construct myself, and intended to be plugged into a power socket, ever going to be "to code"? Not because I can't build something safe, but because I'm never going to get it UL/CSA/TUV/whatever listed & labeled ...

Comment: @brhans. By'code' I was referring to a proper container plus proper grounding. If the OP states they are aware of basic safety code or procedures to avoid water intrusion and shock hazards then we just accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a wall-type dimmer in a portable electrical box (with the proper hardware and accessories) is a common project. People typically take a 6ft (2m) mains power extension cord, chop it in half and wire the "input" and "output" halves into the box.

There is even a commercial product nearily identical to this: A "router speed control" available at retail places like Harbor Freight, et.al.

**NOTE HOWEVER:**

1. Since this involves power mains wiring, it should be done only by someone with experience or expert help executing PROPER methods of maintaining safety for the users of the gadget. There is very significant possibility of creating something lethal if wired improperly.
2. Using a touch-control "downstream" AFTER a dimmer like this is NOT RECOMMENDED because of significant potential for interaction and improper operation between the dimmer and the touch-sensitive circuit.

Comment: Really appreciate your response Richard, thank  you. Regarding the touch control, if I place it before the dimmer (that is between the dimmer and the outlet), it should be fine?

Comment: More in general: Using a typical touch-control AND a dimmer like that in series (in either combination) is the kind of situation where malfunction or interaction would not be surprising.  Besides, most of those touch-control gadgets are built-in to the appliance (like a lamp, etc). So it is not clear how you could put an SCR dimmer downstream from that?